# \cf@encoding vs. \UTFencname: which of them has priority?

Tags: fontspec, font-encodings

There are two macros that bear the name of current font encoding. First is `\cf@encoding` which seems to be set by core of LaTeX 2e and NFSS and changed by the `fontenc` package. Second macro is `\UTFencname`. It is set, in particluar, by `fontspec` package and, perhaps, by some other packages that deal with OTF/TTF fonts and unicode. **What is the relation between these two macros?** I noted `\cf@encoding` also changes when LuaLaTeX runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\cf@encoding` (current font encoding) is the core command. There is also `f@encoding` which is used by `\fontencoding` to store its argument. In general both have the same value except between the `\fontencoding` and the next `\selectfont`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\f@encoding, \cf@encoding; 
\fontencoding{OT1}
\f@encoding, \cf@encoding;
\selectfont 
\f@encoding, \cf@encoding;
\end{document}
```

`\UTFencname` is a command used by xunicode in its various declarations. (xunicode can setup definitions for various encoding names). fontspec sets `UTFencname` to the correct "unicode encoding" name before loading xunicode (EU1 for xetex, EU2 for luatex, the reason for the different names is that the two engines needs different fd-files/font declarations to load fonts as they use a different syntax).

`UTFencname` is normally fix in a document. It doesn't change if you switch to another font encoding:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\f@encoding, \cf@encoding,\UTFencname;
\fontencoding{OT1}
\selectfont 
\f@encoding, \cf@encoding,\UTFencname;
\end{document}
```